# web scrape data from a map with clickable points

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape petrol prices, brand and location from the following website. https://www.motormouth.com.au/

It has an interactive map with clickable locations marked in various colors. It appears to make an api call when you click on a colored location but the response content does not contain the data that is output on the left or in a ticker box when you hover over it.

I am somewhat familiar with python, selenium and beautiful soup but can anyone point me in the right direction for how to approach this?

ok so after swift's hint this is what I got so far. I decided to just scrape the text for each marker. It will get the name and price band. Can anyone point me in the right direction to control the map to pan through an entire area?

code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.motormouth.com.au/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
items = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('gmnoprint')
for item in items:
    print(item.get_attribute('title'))
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Use beautiful soup and Requests.

You can search through the DOM for all `<div class="gmnoprint">` as this element contains a `.svg` file. You will have to analyse the data manually to understand the different `.svg` files that are used, and how they classify the "Gas Stations".

Comment: Your code is required , error trace if any.

Comment: just using the chrome developer tool and trying to inspect the elements to see where I could scrape the data. I found the undocumented api call they used when you click on a gas location but it didn't have all the data I wanted to scrape. Swift - Thanks for the hint about gmnoprint I missed that when I was looking through the html content of the page.

Comment: @Swift is wrong, that data won't be in the DOM if it's coming from API calls. It will be json - you just need to figure how to make the right request.

Comment: Dude I went on the website and inspected the elements. Don't tell me I'm wrong when you haven't checked for yourself. @pguardio